# A stabiliser of a smooth action is a Lie subgroup

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I have got the question at my Lie Groups course.

The *Lie subgroup* is a submanifold of a Lie Group which is also a subgroup.

Assume the Lie Group $G$ acts on a smooth manifold $M$. The stabilizer of a point $G_x$ is a subgroup, I need to show that it is a Lie subgroup as well, i.e. a submanifold.

The statement is mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1377048/477927) question.

I know that every subgroup of a topological group is closed, so $G_x$ is closed, but looks like we should use that M is a manifold and that the acting is continuous, but I have no clue how to make the coordinate definition of a submanifold work here.

UPD [Constant rank argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1915944/477927), [Stabilizer for smooth action](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2001551/477927), [Generalised question for closed orbit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/391315/477927)

Looks like this question was answered two times already but I didn't find it in a brief inspection.

Comment: It is NOT true that every subgroup of a topological group is closed.  For example, on $T^2$ there are dense subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Cartan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem), since $G_x$ is closed, it is automatically a Lie subgroup.

Comment: While I agree with your answer, the OP seems to be under the mistaken impression that $G_x$ is closed because it is a subgroup of a topological group.  Instead, one should use the continuity of the action to show that $G_x$ must be closed.

Comment: Yes, you are right.